# Why "return" to click event is not performing default browser behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I want browser to perform default behaviour after doing some stuff. I used even.preventDefault() and return. But Return to click event is not performing default browser behaviour?

```js
var doneStuff = false;

$('a').on('click', function(event) {

    if(doneStuff){
   alert('done');
        doneStuff = false;
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    alert('doning stuff');
    doneStuff = true;
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://concypt.com">Some Link</a>
```

Comment: If you want to perform the default behaviour then obviously you shouldn't `event.preventDefault()`. The name speaks for itself. It *prevents* the default behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return is performing default browser behavior.
The problem here is `$(this).trigger('click')`.
Unfortunately that only triggers click event handlers that were registered through jQuery (not native js dom events).
So you just should to call native `click` method:

```
var doneStuff = false;

$('a').on('click', function(event) {

    if(doneStuff){
        alert('done');
        doneStuff = false;
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    alert('doning stuff');
    doneStuff = true;
    this.click();
});
```

Take a look at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-ph4xxp?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

> You can do this using set attr at run time and then after click.

```js
var doneStuff = false;

$('a').on('click', function(event) {

    if(doneStuff){
   alert('done');
        doneStuff = false;
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    alert('doning stuff');
    doneStuff = true;
    $(this).attr('href','https://concypt.com')
    $(this)[0].click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Some Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

NOTE: You have to click the link twice. On first click it will do the stuff, and on second click it will do its default action.

```js
var doneStuff = false;

$('a').on('click', function(event) {

    if(doneStuff){
      alert('done');
      doneStuff = false;
      return true;
  }

  event.preventDefault();
  alert('doning stuff');
  doneStuff = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://concypt.com">Some Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I don't really know JQuery to well but in pure JS I think what you're looking for would look something like this.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(a){ 
    var dostuff = function(){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 

        alert('doing stuff'); 
        // some_function(); 
        alert('done'); 

        this.removeEventListener('click',dostuff); 
        this.click(); 
    }
    a.addEventListener('click',dostuff); 
});
```